# Header does not center in the middle

Tags: html, css

Header Row and div do not center in the middle. The line is only at the top. I don't understand where the problem is.
I tried several methods and failed.
I changed the code several times and I couldn't.
I searched a lot on the site, but I didn't find a solution.
I tried to solve it and I didn't find something to solve this problem.
[image: image problem]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #192a56;
    padding-top: 16px 0;
    color: #fff;
}

header>.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 16px
}

nav {
    background-color: #575fcf;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-hamburguer {
    width: 32px;
}

.menu-hamburguer span {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EBAC Motors</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>EBAC Motors</h1>
            <div class="menu-hamburguer">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Em destaque</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Promoções</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contato</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you want it to look because I the description is a bit hard to picture. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @BehRouz Sorry, I think I accidentally overwrote [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33453780). It wasn't bad.

Comment: you added a bottom padding, add the same in the top as well

Comment: @TemaniAfif how do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I vertically center a div element for all browsers using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css)

Comment: align-items: center But, not centered in the middle of the line text. Text is always on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust the padding that you added, which was 16 only at the bottom:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #192a56;
    padding-top: 16px 0;
    color: #fff;
}

header>.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

nav {
    background-color: #575fcf;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-hamburguer {
    width: 32px;
}

.menu-hamburguer span {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>EBAC Motors</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>EBAC Motors</h1>
            <div class="menu-hamburguer">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sobre</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Em destaque</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Promoções</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contato</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header>.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

> padding-bottom: 16px

If you change this to padding: 8px I think this might be what you want.